# Bootstrap hidden-phone assets still load on phone

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an app for mobile and desktop.  There are some assets that I don't want to show or **to load** when on the mobile device.  Using the Bootstrap's [responsive design](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) there is a tag called `hidden-phone` which is used to hide assets when on the phone.  However, they appear to still be loading in the background and using bandwidth.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across the same issue with Bootstrap Responsive Utilities. The problem is that browsers will load all the HTML images first, then apply the CSS rule that Bootstrap uses which is `display:none` for the particular element that you've told it to hide.

One possible solution is to avoid using these utilities and instead, display the images using the CSS `background-image` property. Then, you can choose the same screen breakpoints that Bootstrap uses with their Responsive Utilities or make your own. Below is a simplified example that I've used in the past (set of images for mobile, and a set of images for everything else).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
        #image { 
            background-image: url(largeimage.jpg); 
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            #image { 
                background-image: url(mobileimage.jpg); 
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find more info about Bootstrap breakpoints here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the viewport tag in your header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

If not, you are probably rendering to 1024px wide, which will affect the output.  Also, the sizing is based on screen resolution, not the type of device in use.

If you want to interrogate the browser more, this needs to be done with JS.  I do this in a few places, and inject classes into the HTML element for use with device/browser specific targets in a limited fashion.  You may want to look at Modernizr as well.

---

Given the comments below, and that you are targeting an iframe you do not want loaded for mobile browsers, I would suggest using JavaScript to test for a non-mobile platform, and inject your iframe via JS, rather than using Bootstrap to "hide" the content.

Comment: Note, you may want to specify maximum scale as something like 3, so the user *can* zoom in to see some images better...

Comment: I'm including the viewport.  Same problem.  I should mention that the thing I don't want loading when on mobile is in an iframe.

Comment: The issue at hand.. is the object/view will still load... the class you mention is with regards to visibility... if you don't want it loaded, then I would suggest using JavaScript to test for and inject your iframe for supported platforms.